Trying to optimize my code for TextFields
My current code works but I am wanting to see if there is a better way to do it.
I have a view setup so that once the user starts to enter data in a textfield a new textfield will appear.
What I am wondering is can this be done with a ForEach loop or is there a better way to write this code.
Here is the Model
import FirebaseFirestore
import MetaCodable

@Codable
struct Trip: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    @DocumentID @Default(UUID().uuidString) var id: String?
    
    @Default("") var bol: String
    @Default("") var bol1: String
    @Default("") var bol2: String
    @Default("") var bol3: String
    @Default("") var bol4: String
    @Default("") var bol5: String
    @Default("") var bol6: String
    @Default("") var bol7: String
    @Default("") var bol8: String
    @Default("") var bol9: String
    
    init(
        bol: String = "",
        bol1: String = "",
        bol2: String = "",
        bol3: String = "",
        bol4: String = "",
        bol5: String = "",
        bol6: String = "",
        bol7: String = "",
        bol8: String = "",
        bol9: String = ""
    ) {
        self.bol = bol
        self.bol1 = bol1
        self.bol2 = bol2
        self.bol3 = bol3
        self.bol4 = bol4
        self.bol5 = bol5
        self.bol6 = bol6
        self.bol7 = bol7
        self.bol8 = bol8
        self.bol9 = bol9
    }
}

TextField subview
struct TextFieldRowView: View {
    let title: String
    let placeholder: String
    let width: CGFloat
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ViewThatFits(in: .horizontal) {
            LabeledContent {
                TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .textInputAutocapitalization(.words)
                    .autocorrectionDisabled()
            } label: {
                Text(title)
                    .bold()
            }
            
            VStack {
                Text(title)
                    .bold()
                
                TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
                    .frame(width: width, alignment: .leading)
                    .textInputAutocapitalization(.words)
                    .autocorrectionDisabled()
            }
        }
    }
}

and the view
import SwiftUI

struct AddEditTripView: View {
    
    @FocusState private var focusField: Field?
    
    @State private var bol = ""
    @State private var bol1 = ""
    @State private var bol2 = ""
    @State private var bol3 = ""
    @State private var bol4 = ""
    @State private var bol5 = ""
    @State private var bol6 = ""
    @State private var bol7 = ""
    @State private var bol8 = ""
    @State private var bol9 = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            // MARK: - Trip Information
            Section {
                // MARK: - BOL
                TextFieldRowView(title: "BOL:", placeholder: "bol", width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 230, text: $bol)
                    .focused($focusField, equals: .bol)
                    .submitLabel(.next)
                
                if !bol.isEmpty {
                    TextFieldRowView(title: "BOL:", placeholder: "bol", width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 230, text: $bol1)
                        .focused($focusField, equals: .bol1)
                        .submitLabel(.next)
                }
                
                if !bol1.isEmpty {
                    TextFieldRowView(title: "BOL:", placeholder: "bol", width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 230, text: $bol2)
                        .focused($focusField, equals: .bol2)
                        .submitLabel(.next)
                }
                
                if !bol2.isEmpty {
                    TextFieldRowView(title: "BOL:", placeholder: "bol", width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 230, text: $bol3)
                        .focused($focusField, equals: .bol3)
                        .submitLabel(.next)
                }
                
                if !bol3.isEmpty {
                    TextFieldRowView(title: "BOL:", placeholder: "bol", width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 230, text: $bol4)
                        .focused($focusField, equals: .bol4)
                        .submitLabel(.next)
                }
                
                if !bol4.isEmpty {
                    TextFieldRowView(title: "BOL:", placeholder: "bol", width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 230, text: $bol5)
                        .focused($focusField, equals: .bol5)
                        .submitLabel(.next)
                }
                
                if !bol5.isEmpty {
                    TextFieldRowView(title: "BOL:", placeholder: "bol", width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 230, text: $bol6)
                        .focused($focusField, equals: .bol6)
                        .submitLabel(.next)
                }
                
                if !bol6.isEmpty {
                    TextFieldRowView(title: "BOL:", placeholder: "bol", width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 230, text: $bol7)
                        .focused($focusField, equals: .bol7)
                        .submitLabel(.next)
                }
                
                if !bol7.isEmpty {
                    TextFieldRowView(title: "BOL:", placeholder: "bol", width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 230, text: $bol8)
                        .focused($focusField, equals: .bol8)
                        .submitLabel(.next)
                }
                
                if !bol8.isEmpty {
                    TextFieldRowView(title: "BOL:", placeholder: "bol", width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 230, text: $bol9)
                        .focused($focusField, equals: .bol9)
                        .submitLabel(.next)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension AddEditTripView {
    private enum Field {
        case bol, bol1, bol2, bol3, bol4, bol5, bol6, bol7, bol8, bol9
    }
    
    private func focusNextField() {
        switch focusField {
        case .bol:
            focusField = .bol1
        case .bol1:
            focusField = .bol2
        case .bol2:
            focusField = .bol3
        case .bol3:
            focusField = .bol4
        case .bol4:
            focusField = .bol5
        case .bol5:
            focusField = .bol6
        case .bol6:
            focusField = .bol7
        case .bol7:
            focusField = .bol8
        case .bol8:
            focusField = .bol9
        case .bol9:
            focusField = nil
        case .none:
            break
        }
    }
}


Why don't you make a recursive view component?

Just use an array to store the bols?

@ClausJørgensen Thank you for the reply I have never heard of that and will look into.

Store all the bols into an array, and iterate over that array with a ForEach.
@FocusState private var focusField: Field?

@State private var bols = Array(repeating: "", count: 10)

var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section {
            ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                if i == 0 || !bols[i - 1].isEmpty {
                    TextFieldRowView(
                        title: "BOL:",
                        placeholder: "bol",
                        width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 230,
                        text: $bols[i]
                    )
                    .focused($focusField, equals: Field(rawValue: i))
                    .submitLabel(.next)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Note the i == 0 disjunction. This shows the first text field unconditionally, and all the other text fields are only shown if the previous field is not empty.
Note Field(rawValue: i). Field should have Int as its raw value type. This makes it easy to create values of Field with Ints. You can also easily write a nextField method:
enum Field: Int {
    case bol, bol1, bol2, bol3, bol4, bol5, bol6, bol7, bol8, bol9
    
    func nextField() -> Field? {
        Field(rawValue: rawValue + 1)
    }
}

Then moving to the next field is as easy as,
.onSubmit {
    focusField = focusField?.nextField()
}

Also consider just using a simple Int instead of Field.
